How to update GDB version for WSL in CLion?
I was trying to install valgrind memcheck for my CLion in Windows 10. It required switching to WSL toolchain and it wasn't a big deal but there is a problem that I couldn't correctly deal with - Bundled GDB had version of 12.1, making it impossible to debug my code with debug points (at least, CLion tech support said that GDB version was the deal at their forum and recomended installing new version of CLion where GDB 14.1 is Bundled). Not wanting to update CLion I manually set GDB executable file to the one that's in the CLion folder (...\bin\gdb\win\x64\bin\gdb.exe) because this GDB had version of 13.1 and now it just won't launch with debug. When I try to launch with debug I get the following error:
The directory is correct and file exists, it is run by gcc correctly.
So in general my question is how to make CLion use gdb of newer version for WSL toolchain so that I could debug my code?
I'm using CLion version 2023.2.3., Windows 10, WSL Ubuntu 22.02.04 LTS

If you have GDB downloaded or builded on your WSL just specify it in the Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains and use it.
